# Как обновить в БД несколько строк в одной таблице?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем здравствуйте, у меня есть функция которая добавляет несколько строк в БД взяв значения из массива

```
                    function createQuery($id, $a, $b){
                    $query = "INSERT INTO opisanie (x,text,text_opis) VALUES ";
                    $limit = count($a);
                    for($i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                        $query .= "('{$id}','{$a[$i]}', '{$b[$i]}')".($i!=$limit-1?',':'');
                    }
                    $res = mysql_query($query);
                }

                $aText = $_POST['form_text_o'];
                $aOpis = $_POST['form_text_opis'];

                $query = createQuery($id, $aText, $aOpis);
```

Как мне таким же принципом обновить строки в БД? Подскажите пожалуйста..

Comment: вы можете воспользоватся даже этим же самым insert добавив к нему ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query

Comment: Опять [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) - потыкайте в него палкой и перепишите везде на `mysqli`

Comment: Приведите конкретные условия для выбора обновляемых строк, тогда можно будет показать пример SQL запроса,

Comment: @Mike спасибо за комментарий, все более подробно изучил и составил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось все достаточно просто, в конце я добавил `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE text = VALUES(text), text_opis = VALUES(text_opis)` что означало если `X` - уникальный ключ будет совпадать, то нужно в этой строке обновить таблицы `text` и `text_opis`, если же совпадений не будет, то добавить новую строку со значениями `text` и `text_opis`. Отличное решение для того чтобы одновременно обновлять и добавлять новые записи.

```
            function createQuery($id, $a, $b){
                $query = "INSERT INTO opisanie (x,text,text_opis) VALUES ";
                $limit = count($a);
                $update = "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE text = VALUES(text), text_opis = VALUES(text_opis)";
                for($i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                    $query .= "('{$id}','{$a[$i]}', '{$b[$i]}')".($i!=$limit-1?',':'');
                }
                $res = mysql_query($query.$update);
            }

            $aText = $_POST['form_text_o'];
            $aOpis = $_POST['form_text_opis'];

            $query = createQuery($id, $aText, $aOpis);
```

Спасибо @Mike за комментарий.